# Sending print output to a file in Python script

Tags: python

How would I go about sending the output of a print command to a new file? I have a python script where I need to redirect the output at the end of the print statement to a file but I can't seem to find a way to accomplish the redirect. Why doesn't "print (stuff to be redirected) > newfile.txt" work?

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Redirecting with `>` is for the command line. For example, `C:\Users\russ\Documents> py mymodule.py > output.txt`. Telling your Python program itself to create a file is a different process (see alfasin's comment, above).

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4675728/redirect-stdout-to-a-file-in-python), you could set the standard output to a file object.

```
import sys
sys.stdout = open('file', 'w')
```

Then, all your print statements should go directly to that file.